# Use a for loop to show that a list and a tupel have the same order of elements in python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

So in Python, I have a tupel and I have a list and they do have the same elements and the elements are in the same order in both of them and I have to prove the fact that they are  in the same  order using a for loop.

I know how to show that the elements of the tupel are  in the list and vice versa but how can I show that the order is the same.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your problem you're not sure how to synchronously loop through both a list and a tuple?

Comment: Use `zip` in your `for` loop to loop over both containers simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the list and the tuple have the same length.

Then, using a for loop check whether `tup[i] == li[i]` for all `i` in `range(0, len(tup))`.

If both collections have the same element at the same index, they must have the same order.

---

Once you understand the above, check out the function [**`zip`**](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#zip), and print the results of `list(zip(li, tup))`. Try to re-write the function above using `zip`.